# How do I get MySQL to recognize custom column names?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, floating-point

```
SELECT Y/X as Z
FROM (
    SELECT
    (count(county) FROM `cleanup_site_list_2011` WHERE county='kings') as X,
    (count(county) FROM `cleanup_site_list_2011` WHERE county='kings' AND people != 0) as Y
    FROM `cleanup_site_list_2011`
) as innertable
```

In the above example the two "SELECT ..." represent nested queries of any description (X and Y will be integers).  When I try to use this statement I get the error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'Y' in 'field list'
```

How would I get MySQL to recognize the names of the columns I created?  Also, once the math works out, how would I make the division result in a float?  Or does it do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this is to give the columns their 'custom names' in a subquery, then use those custom names in the surrounding query:

```
SELECT 
  Y/X as Z -- moved to outer query
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (...) as X, -- assign custom names in subquery
    (...) as Y, 
  FROM `table`
) as innertable;
```

---

For the second question:

```
mysql> select 4 / 3;
+--------+
| 4 / 3  |
+--------+
| 1.3333 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does that answer it?  (MySQL 5)

More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_divide).

Comment: +1 it works. short runnable example: `SELECT (Y/X) as Z 
FROM (SELECT 5 AS X, 7 as Y) AS innertable` -> result 1.4000

Comment: Must be more to my problem because neither this nor the other format are working.  Let me post the full statement I'm trying.

Comment: @MathiasSchnell -- I can't get your query to work, is it missing `SELECT`s in the sub-sub-queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.x, t2.y, t2.y/t1.x z
FROM (SELECT x ...) t1, 
(SELECT y ...) t2, 
FROM `table`
```

Comment: Probably should've mentioned, the queries are all of a single table.

Comment: it doesn't work in the form you wrote, example: `SELECT (t1.Y/t2.X) as Z FROM  (SELECT 5 AS X) t1,(SELECT 7 AS Y) t2` -- t works removing t1 and t2 prefix, strange. -> `SELECT (Y/X) as Z ...`

Comment: SELECT (t1.Y/t2.X) as Z FROM (SELECT 5 AS X from dual) t1, (SELECT 7 AS Y from dual) t2

Comment: from dual is not necessary with MySQL. anyway, try it, also this query doesn't work and MySQL 5.1, it gives me the following error `Unknown column 't1.Y' in 'field list'`